# For loop not catching all items in list for function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

So I'm doing a project in Codeademy that is suppose to work as a censor for emails coming in. I've done a function to censor single words and phrases, and the next step is to censor words and phrases from a list given to use.

```
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "learning algorithms", "her", "herself"]
```

I got a simple function that is suppose to go through the list of censored terms and replace them with "*" in the length of the censored terms.

```
  def censor_list(txt):
  for term in proprietary_terms:
      if term in txt: 
        txt_censored = txt.replace(term, ("*" * len(term)))
      return txt_censored
```

However, when I ran the function, it only censored the first word in the list. As shown in the email below:

> Good Morning, Board of Investors,
>
> Lots of updates this week. The learning algorithms have been working
> better than we could have ever expected. Our initial internal data
> dumps have been completed and we have proceeded with the plan to
> connect the system to the internet and wow! The results are mind
> blowing.
>
> She is learning faster than ever. Her learning rate now that *** has
> access to the world wide web has increased exponentially, far faster
> than we had though the learning algorithms were capable of.
>
> Not only that, but we have configured her personality matrix to allow
> for communication between the system and our team of researchers.
> That's how we know *** considers herself to be a ***! We asked!
>
> How cool is that? We didn't expect a personality to develop this early
> on in the process but it seems like a rudimentary sense of self is
> starting to form. This is a major step in the process, as having a
> sense of self and self-preservation will allow her to see the problems
> the world is facing and make hard but necessary decisions for the
> betterment of the planet.
>
> We are a-buzz down in the lab with excitement over these developments
> and we hope that the investors share our enthusiasm.
>
> Till next month, Francine, Head Scientist

I've tried to see if indention was the issue, but I only get indent errors in return. The function is suppose to catch all of the words and phrases in the email and censor them, but it only censored the word "she" or "herself". I even tried to see if I needed another for loop to go through each term, but it only censored every single word in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `txt` as variable, not `txt_censored`, like this:

```
def censor_list(txt):
  for term in proprietary_terms:
      if term in txt:
        txt = txt.replace(term, ("*" * len(term)))
  return txt
```

string in python is immutable. You will not change the txt you passed in. You are creating new `txt` string every time you replace it, so it is fine in this way (you can talk about performance, but that's a different question)

If you use `txt_censored` like you do, you are discarding your fruit of work except your last replacement.

Answer (score 1):

just change:

```
return txt_censored
```

to:

```
return txt
```